# Showing restriction of a function to a subset is Lipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Question:
>
> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be $C^{\infty}$.
>
> Prove that, for any compact subset D of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the restriction of f to D is Lipschitz.

Without any formal lesson in real analysis, this certainly is a great deal of challenge for me and help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: uniformly continuous implies Lipschitz, right?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: what about $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ ?

Comment: Hint: Since $f$ is $C^{\infty}$, $f'$ is bounded on any compact subset.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the hint in the comments: As $f\in C^\infty$, $f'$ is continuous, hence it is bounded on compact subsets.

Let $x,y\in D$. W.l.o.g. assume that $D$ is convex (we can always replace it by a closed ball containing it). By the mean value theorem we have
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\int_0^1 f'(tx+(1-t)y)(x-y)\,dt\right|\ \\
&\leq \int_0^1|f'(tx+(1-t)y)(x-y)|\,dt\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in[0,1]}\|f'(tx+(1-t)y)\||x-y|\\
&\leq \sup_{z\in D}\|f'(z)\||x-y|.
\end{align}
Notice that I denote by $|\cdot|$ the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ and by $\|\cdot\|$ the associated matrix norm. But since all norms on Euclidean space are equivalent, the statement holds regardless of the choice of the norms.